# How to mock $window.Notification

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am still learning the ropes when it comes to unit testing with angular. I have an angular service that I use to create HTML5 notifications. Code is similar to the following:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('blah')
    .factory('OffPageNotification', offPageNotificationFactory);

  function offPageNotificationFactory($window) {
    //Request permission for HTML5 notifications as soon as we can
    if($window.Notification && $window.Notification.permission !== 'denied')     {
      $window.Notification.requestPermission(function (status) { });
    }

    function OffPageNotification () {
      var self = Object.create(OffPageNotification.prototype);
      self.visibleNotification = null;
      return self;
    }


 OffPageNotification.prototype.startNotification = function (options) {
      var self = this;
      self.options = options;
      if(self.options.showHtml5Notification && (!self.options.onlyShowIfPageIsHidden || $window.document.hidden)) {
    if($window.Notification && $window.Notification.permission !== 'denied')     {
          self.visibleNotification = new $window.Notification('Notification',     {
              body: self.options.notificationText,
              icon: self.options.notificationIcon
            });
        }
      }
    };

    .
    .
    .
  return new OffPageNotification();
  }
})();
```

I am attempting to write unit tests for this but am unsure how to mock $window.Notification so it can be used as both a constructor...

```
self.visibleNotification = new $window.Notification(....)
```

and also contain properties

```
if($window.Notification && $window.Notification.permission !== 'denied')
```

and methods....

```
$window.Notification.requestPermission(
```

An example of something I have tried is:

```
     describe('startNotification', function() {

     beforeEach(function() {
       var mockNotification = function (title, options) {
         this.title = title;
         this.options = options;
         this.requestPermission = sinon.stub();
       };

       mockNotification.prototype.permission = 'granted';

       mockWindow = {
         Notification: new mockNotification('blah', {}),
         document: {hidden: true}
       };

       inject(function (_OffPageNotification_) {
         OffPageNotification = _OffPageNotification_;
       });
     });

     it('should display a html5 notification if the relevant value is true in the options, and permission has been granted', function(){
       var options = {
         showHtml5Notification: true,
         onlyShowIfPageIsHidden: true
       };
       OffPageNotification.startNotification(options);
     });
  });
```

I get an error saying '$window.Notification is not a constructor' with this setup and I understand why (I am passing in an instantiated version of the mockNotification). But if I set mockWindow.Notification = mockNotification then I get an error when it calls requestPermission since this is undefined.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Notification` should be a constructor. And it should have static [properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification#Static_properties) and [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification#Static_methods).

All of the relevant properties of mockNotification are instance properties, while they should be static:

```
function MockNotification() {}

MockNotification.title = title;
MockNotification.options = options;
MockNotification.requestPermission = sinon.stub();

   mockWindow = {
     Notification: MockNotification,
     document: {hidden: true}
   };
```